# Disabling Text Boxes depeding on Text Boxes values using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

we are using MVVM Pattern in our application, we had a screen with 10 text Boxes , whenever they entered value in any one text box others should be disabled. Whenever i enter the value the event gets fired and i am able to disable other 9 text boxes.

Here Comes the Problem , The event Doesn't get fired when i remove/Backspace the value

**Example :**
    Say i have 3 Text Boxes **TB1,TB2,TB3**  for each of these Text Boxes the Text Property Binding is Like Text="{Binding **TextBox1**,Mode=TwoWay,**UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged**}" For TB1,... similary to other Text BoxesTB2 and TB3.So Now when i write some thing in the UI in **TB1** the Set event is fired for **TextBox1** Property and i am disabling the TB2 and TB3 .Now, When i Delete/Backspace a Single Number/Char in **TB1** the Set Event is Not Fired for Enabling the other 2 Text Boxes since there is No Value in TextBox **TB1**.

```
View : 

<StackPanel orintation = "Horizontal" Margin = "20,0,20,0">
<TextBox Text = {Binding TextBox1,Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged} IsEnbaled={Binding IsTextBox1Enabled}>
<TextBox Text = {Binding TextBox2,Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged} IsEnbaled={Binding IsTextBox2Enabled}>
<TextBox Text = {Binding TextBox3,Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged} IsEnbaled={Binding IsTextBox3Enabled}>
</StackPanel>

ViewModel:

private bool _isTextBox1Enabled = true;
private bool _isTextBox2Enabled = true;
private bool _isTextBox3Enabled = true;

/// Encapsulating Above 3 _isTextBoxEnabled Properties  

private string _textBox1;
private String _textBox2;
private string _textbox3;

Public String TextBox1
{
    get { Return _textBox1;}
    set 
    {
        _textBox1 = value;
        if (TextBox1 > 0)
        {
            _isTextBox2Enabled  = false;
            _isTextBox3Enabled  = false;
        }   
        else
        {
            _isTextBox2Enabled  = true;
            _isTextBox3Enabled  = true;
        }           
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TextBox1");
    }
}

Public String TextBox2
{
    get { Return _textBox2;}
    set 
    {
        _textBox2 = value;
        if (TextBox2 > 0)
        {
            _isTextBox1Enabled  = false;
            _isTextBox3Enabled  = false;
        }   
        else
        {
            _isTextBox1Enabled  = true;
            _isTextBox3Enabled  = true;
        }           
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TextBox2");
    }
}

Public String TextBox3
{
    get { Return _textBox3;}
    set 
    {
        _textBox3 = value;
        if (TextBox3 > 0)
        {
            _isTextBox2Enabled  = false;
            _isTextBox1Enabled  = false;
        }   
        else
        {
            _isTextBox2Enabled  = true;
            _isTextBox1Enabled  = true;
        }       
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TextBox3");
    }
}
```

Comment: LostFocus seems a better approach but I doubt this design because you are disabling the user from tabbing to/focussing the next textbox.

Comment: Lost Focus will work, but the requirement is like as and when the user is typing the other text boxes should be disabled / Enabled based on , whether the value exists or empty.

Comment: Could you, clearly, describe how it should work? It is not clear to me when exactly textboxes should be enabled/disabled. Perhaps a binding between the Enabled property of each textbox and properties of the ViewModel might do the trick.

Comment: In the Above Scenario only 1 text box should have a value.

Comment: Please put this in the question, this way it is very hard to read and others might not see it.

Comment: so thats what my problem is about, whenever the user is typing in the text boxes automatically other text boxes should be enabled/ disabled.depending whether the value is there or not.

Answer (score 1):

To enable updates on any change of the text value (without having to lose focus) add the UpdateSourceTrigger flag to the binding.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: but the problem in "Property Changed" event is Setter for MyTextProperty is not fired when i delete all the values and empty the text box , in order to enable other text boxes.